# In player v player combat, can a player resume attacking after I have passed?

Tags: mage-knight

The ranged/siege attack phase and the melee attack phases end when both players have passed "in succession."  Does this mean that, after passing, one could choose to act, such as in Bridge? i.e. A attacks, B attacks, A passes, B attacks, A attacks.

Answer (score 2):

> **pg. 10, Ranged and Siege Attacks, #6**
>
> After resolving the attack, the other player gets his chance to be
>   the attacker, and the Ranged and Siege Attack phase continues
>   with both players alternating the roles of attacker and blocker.
>   If both players pass on attacking in succession, the phase ends.

This is worded in a slightly confusing manner because of:

> both players alternating the roles of attacker and blocker

as opposed to

> If both players pass on attacking in succession, the phase ends.

These seem to be at odds with each other. However, the latter wording is more definitive because it specifies the conditions that need to be met for the phase to end: both players must pass in succession. The wording before it must then be an oversight.

That said, the usefulness of this is questionable. The only reason I can see to want multiple attacks is to "waste" your opponent's "big block" cards, which are fairly rare, while stacking attacks has a number of benefits (only suffering "rounding down" effects once, having a choice of targeting units, etc).

**tl;dr**

Yes, you can attack using separate attacks as long as you want.